# Unable to open network PDF file from embedded link inside another PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, hyperlink, adobe, axacropdf

I use a small program to open a main PDF file used by multiple employees. If open the given file on the Network (without using the program) and select the hyperlink inside the PDF, it will open correctly.

However, when I run my program to open that given file and try to select the hyperlink inside the PDF, I receive a "Security Block" error:

[image]

---

The control I am using to display the PDF on the program is:

[image]

And I use the following code to load the PDF file:

```
Private Sub UpdateFile()
    Dim fileList As IEnumerable(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(DrawingsRootDirectory, "*.PDF", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    Me.AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile(fileList.Last)
    Me.AxAcroPDF1.Refresh()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
```

I'm not quite sure why opening the PDF file via a program would prevent it from using the hyperlinks inside that given file. Any ideas?